# Change names of translated standard paths like "Eigene Dateien" (Documents)

Tags: windows-10, path, language

I just got a new work PC, which unfortunately was set up with a German copy of Windows 10. I already changed the keyboard and display language, but I noticed that the path names of the standard directories like "Documents" actually have German path names:

```
Z:\> ls


    Directory: Z:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2015-10-05     09:57                .ssh
d-r---       2015-10-05     10:30                Desktop
d-r---       2015-10-05     10:04                Downloads
d-r---       2015-10-02     10:57                Eigene Dateien
-a----       2015-10-02     15:02             70 .bash_history


Z:\> cd '.\Eigene Dateien\'
Z:\Eigene Dateien> ls


    Directory: Z:\Eigene Dateien


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-r---       2015-10-02     10:56                Eigene Bilder
d-r---       2015-10-02     10:57                Eigene Musik
d-r---       2015-10-02     10:57                Eigene Videos
d-----       2015-10-01     13:45                Visual Studio 2013
d-----       2015-10-01     14:18                WindowsPowerShell


Z:\Eigene Dateien>
```

where

```
Eigene Dateien == Documents
Eigene Bilder  == Pictures
Eigene Musik   == Music
Eigene Videos  == Videos
```

Windows Explorer actually shows the English names, but the real paths appear to be the ones shown in PowerShell. This is quite annoying, because some programs may assume the English directory names and then put their data in a directory *actually* called "Documents" (which also means that Windows Explorer now displays two directories of that name).

I would have expected all of these paths to always keep their English names and be referred to by some sort of symbolic path (and only displayed in German in Windows Explorer if that's the display language).

Is there a way to change all of these back to their English standard names? (Alternatively, is there some underlying system language which is still different from the display language, which I might be able to change?)

Comment: Download the Windows 10 installation disk and install the English version of Windows 10.  Since you were able to install a language pack you should have no problems doing this.

Comment: @Ramhound I was hoping for a less time consuming solution that wouldn't require a reinstall.

Comment: You want the names of system folders, which have already been created in German, to use their English names.  What you want isn't possible.  You could create a new user, and the folders within the user's profile, would be in English just not the other system folders.